# Bundle Identifier Problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cfbundleidentifier

I’m having issues generating new bundle identifiers through the provisioning profile. When I click new New App Id and enter the required details it keeps generating the same bundle id.

This is what I am entering:
Description: “My app name”
Bundle Seed ID: “Use Team ID”
Bundle Identifier: “*”

I don’t understand the problem as I have been successfully able to generate new identifiers in the past.

Any help? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Have you been able to generate new identifiers eventually?

Comment: Afraid not. No idea what is happening.

Comment: I'm thinking Apple removed this, because having the same seed id for all your applications keeps all doors open.  It means you can always let your applications interact, which is not really a security problem because it are all your applications anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried logging out. Restarting your browser and clearing your cache?

Btw, I notice from an email today that Apple now allow you change the Bundle ID in itunesConnect before binary submission (in case that helps).

Comment: Yeah, tried all that. These are all apps generated over the past week. It’s been an on-going problem.